Mechanisms and ex-ante vs ex-post equality
I was studying an allocation problem, where $n$ agents are to be allotted in $m$ rooms. Each agent has a preference relation defined over the rooms, and there can be at most $k$ people in each room. I want to allocate the agents to rooms such that the allocation in Pareto Optimal and also "not very unequal" in some sense. And, of course, the mechanism used should be strategy proof, as I do not know the preferences beforehand.
I read that serial dictatorship would give me a Pareto Optimal allocation, and it is also an Incentive Compatible mechanism. Furthermore, I thought an easy way to ensure equality, ex ante, would be to just randomise the order of serial dictatorship before implementing it.
This, I feel, however, would not ensure that the outcome is "not very unequal" ex post. This is what I mean by this: consider all the Pareto Optimal allocations. Measure the "inequality" in each allocation using any measure. Does Serial Dicatorship with randomised order of dictatorship guarantee that the most equal of these allocations is chosen (I think it does not)?
I also read about Probabilistic Serial mechanism, but I am not sure it is always Pareto Optimal. Other mechanisms such as Top-Trading Cycles and some mechanisms that ensure envy free allocations do not seem to be Pareto optimal or strategy proof in general.
More broadly, and primarily, I am interested in the general literature on mechanisms that try to ensure as much equality as possible, and whether there is always a trade off with Pareto optimality or strategy proofness.
Can anybody briefly discuss the major mechanisms that try to do that, and point towards resources I can refer to?
